# Selecting rows that match a column in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes df_Participants and df_Movements and I want to keep the rows in `df_Movements` only if a participant is on in `df_Participants`.

df_Participants:

```
         id                          
0    1053.0     
1    1052.0  
2    1049.0
```

df_Movements

```
     id           participant                    
0    3902         1053                   
1    3901         1053                                  
611  2763          979                   
612  2762          979
```

Expected results:

```
     id           participant                    
0    3902         1053                   
1    3901         1053
```

what I have tried so far:

```
remove_incomplete_submissions = True
if remove_incomplete_submissions:

    df_Movements = df_Movements.loc[df_Movements['participant'].isin(df_Participants['id'])]
```

When I check the number of unique participants, it does not match. I know this is simple, but I can't seem to notice the issue here.

Comment: using `isin` is a good way to go there and what you did seems right. What do you mean by *the number of unique participants does not match*?

Comment: @Ben.T I hadn't seen your suggestion before. I added you in my answer.

Comment: I am expecting 40 unique participants, but I keep getting 28 (also, I am sure that there are 40 unique participants).

Comment: My mistake, I was saving the changes to the original CSV file every time I run the script. Hence, I never got the matching number.

Comment: @Corralien no pb, if I did not spend the time to write an answer but someone else did, then I can't be mad really :p but in this case, OP already wrote this method with `isin` in the code shown. so I was more confused on  why is was not working in their case

Answer (score 0):

You can use merge:

```
new_df = df_Participants.merge(df_Movements, how='left', left_on='id', right_on='participant')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `isin` to create a boolean mask and get rows that match the condition:

```
>>> df_Movements[df_Movements['participant'].isin(df_Participants['id'])]

     id  participant
0  3902         1053
1  3901         1053
```

*Edit: as suggested too by @Ben.T in comments*